# What causes a css caption to overlay another image in this table?

Tags: html, css, hover

I have this css caption effect:

```css
.cell {
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
}
.caption {} .cell .caption {
  opacity: 0;
  text-decoration-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  background: #eaeaea;
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
}
.cell:hover .caption {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 2px #777;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<table style="text-align: left; width: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

  <c:forEach var="product" items="${categoryProducts}" varStatus="iter">

    <td>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle; width: 180px; text-align: center; height: 180px;" class="cell">
            <a href="product?${product.id}">



              <img class="img" alt="" src="${initParam.productImagePath}${product.name}.jpg" />

              <div class="caption">
                <br>view details</div>

            </a>
            <br>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle; width: 140px; text-align: center;">${product.name}
            <br>
          </td>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle; width: 125px; text-align: center;">$ ${product.price}
            <br>
          </td>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle; width: 125px; text-align: center;">

            <form action="addToWishlist" method="post">
              <br>
              <br>
              <input name="productId" value="${product.id}" type="hidden">

              <input class="submit" value="<fmt:message key='AddToWishlist'/>" type="submit">
            </form>
            <br>
          </td>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle; width: 123px; text-align: center;">


            <form action="addToCart" method="post">
              <br>
              <br>

              <input name="productId" value="${product.id}" type="hidden">
              <input class="submit" value="<fmt:message key='AddToCart'/>" type="submit">


            </form>
            <br>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

The code in itself works perfectly fine. The caption shows as expected. The only thing tho, when there's an image inside of the  cell, there is a display problem when mouse hover the image as shown from my local browser run from the IDE:

[image]

The caption overlays the next cell... What could cause this? I tried to play around with the `.img` and the `.caption` but cannot seem to find a solution...

Here the full image overlay caption effect i'm trying to accomplish:
http://www.corelangs.com/css/box/caption.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem in your screenshot is the caption of the bottom image overlaying on top of the first image? Not sure I understand this correctly, but if so there are three simple solutions I can think about:

- Increase the margin between your images / rows
- On :hover, increase margin, although that could be poor UX
- Increase opacity from 0.7 to 1 so it overlays, but you cannot see the first cell through it

Comment: Sorry for this... english is my third language. So basically, if you take a look at the JSFiddle, the caption effect works fine without picture. When there's an image in the cell, the caption starts acting up... The caption you see is the caption created by hovering your mouse over the first picture. I believe when there's an image placed in the cell, it misplaces the caption because the caption is supposed to cover the image and the cell as shown in JSFiddle.

Comment: I took a better screenshot with the mouse integrated so you can have a better idea. I also added a link of the effect I'm trying to accomplish as well. Hope it helps.

Comment: Got it. You need to add: `bottom: 0; top: 0;` for .caption
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/51awayds/)

Comment: Thanks for your help bro! Working nicely!